# запятая в сложном предложении

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, сложное-предложение

Помогите, пожалуйста, обосновать запятую (или ее отсутствие) после "очнулся". Спасибо.

*Он с кем-то танцевал, с кем-то обнимался, кого-то целовал — очнулся, только когда увидел перед глазами чёрно-белый ряд клавиш.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Он с кем-то танцевал, с кем-то обнимался, кого-то целовал — очнулся, **только когда** увидел перед глазами чёрно-белый ряд клавиш.*

Пояснение

Розенталь: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=137#pp137

6. Если перед подчинительным союзом стоят **усилительные частицы как раз, только, лишь, исключительно** и т. п., то перед ними ставится **запятая** (вопреки интонации, так как при чтении пауза перед ними не делается): Катя вышла из столовой, как раз когда мы шагнули друг к другу через какие-то чемоданы (Кав.); Я эту работу выполню, только если буду свободен (ср.: …если только буду свободен);

Comment: Интересно, однако. Я бы поставил запятую перед "только" на основании того, что данная частица имеет отношение к пропущенному "тогда". Но с Розенталем тоже согласен.

Comment: @Бот Ботович Она НЕ имеет отношение к "пропущенному" ТОГДА. Ибо ничего здесь не пропущено. Уберите "только" и убедитесь сами.

Comment: А разве? По-моему, каждое придаточное предложение должно относиться к какому -либо определяемому слову, которое, в свою очередь, может содержать зависимые слова. Например, **он знает что делать** равносильно **он знает *только* то, что делать**. Но это только  моя точка зрения.